# Making New Arrays using the contents of the text file

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new in using python
the contents of b.txt is

132,21,5,63

43,21,2,3,5,2,1

Basically, I am trying to make a new array using the contents on the text file

I am wondering why this code doesn't work

```
x=open('b.txt','r')
for line in x:
 a=[]
 b=line[0]
 c=0
 while c+1<len(line):
    while line[c]!=',' and line[c+1]!=',':
        b=b+line[c+1]
        c=c+1
    a.append(int(b))
    c=c+1
print a
```

Help pls,

Comment: In the line "    while line[c]!=',' and line[c+1]!=',':" , "line[c+1]!=','" is enough as condition. In other word , "line[c]!=','" is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, a more pythonic way of doing it would be:

```py
fileHandler = open('b.txt', 'r')
listOfLists = []
for line in fileHandler:
    listOfLists.append(line.split(","))

print listOfLists
```

This would generate, in your example, this result:

```
[["132","21","5","63"],["43","21","2","3","5","2","1"]]
```

If you want them all in a single list (like `["132","21","5","63","43","21","2","3","5","2","1"]`), you can exchange the `append` method with the `extend` method.

Comment: i would like to seperate it into 2 arrays and convert the strings to integers? how should i do it?

Comment: Well, since you have the array of strings, you can iterate through the array (as in `for element in array:`), converting each element to a integer (with the `int` method).

Answer (score 0):

One other code alternative could be:

```
import re
result = []
with open("b.txt", 'r') as b_file:
    content = b_file.read()
    result = re.split(",|\n", content)
    result = = [int(r) for r in result if r!='']
print result
```